# Control webpack compilation progress output - Laravel Mix/Envoy

Tags: laravel, webpack, progress-bar, laravel-mix, laravel-envoy

Using the command like `npm run development` through Laravel Envoy, makes every line outputted back making hundreds of lines like this in the console:

```
[remote@server]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 65% building 145/150 modules 5 active /home/remote/example.com/node_modules/date-fns/sub_years/index.js
[remote@server]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 65% building 146/150 modules 4 active /home/remote/example.com/node_modules/date-fns/sub_years/index.js
[remote@server]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 65% building 147/150 modules 3 active /home/remote/example.com/node_modules/date-fns/sub_years/index.js
[remote@server]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 65% building 147/151 modules 4 active /home/remote/example.com/node_modules/array-includes/index.js
[remote@server]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 65% building 148/151 modules 3 active /home/remote/example.com/node_modules/array-includes/index.js
[remote@server]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 65% building 148/152 modules 4 active /home/remote/example.com/node_modules/vue-google-charts/index.js
[remote@server]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 65% building 148/153 modules 5 active /home/remote/example.com/node_modules/@deveodk/vue-toastr/dist/@deveodk/vue-toastr.js
[remote@server]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 65% building 148/154 modules 6 active /home/remote/example.com/node_modules/pluralize/pluralize.js
[remote@server]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 65% building 148/155 modules 7 active /home/remote/example.com/node_modules/vue-js-modal/dist/index.js
[remote@server]: <s> [webpack.Progress] 65% building 148/156 modules 8 active /home/remote/example.com/node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js
```

Is there a way to minimize progress output to only a few lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things are important to understand here:

- package.json contains npm commands like `npm run development`, `npm run production`
- here's how one of these might look like:

`"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",`

- the progress output is initiated by `--progress` argument in above mentioned command
- the progress output is using [ProgressPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/progress-plugin/) in the background

The idea is to remove `--progress` argument from the command so it looks like

`"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",`

but to instantiate it manually as a plugin like so, in `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProgressPlugin((percentage, message) => {
            // An idea to show the line only if percentage is divisible by 5.
            if (percentage * 100 % 5 === 0) {
                console.log(`${(percentage * 100).toFixed()}% ${message}`);
            }
        })
    ],
});
```

Here's how revised output could look like:

```
0% compiling
10% building
10% building
25% building
40% building
40% building
70% building
70% building
70% finish module graph
70% finish module graph
75% module optimization
70% building
70% building
80% chunk modules optimization
85% chunk reviving
85% chunk reviving
95% emitting
95% emitting
```

The idea is borrowed from this article explaining [how ProgressPlugin works](https://medium.com/@artempetrovcode/how-webpack-progressplugin-works-7e7301a3d919)